# Ldap Query - Configuration using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-ldap

I have a Spring boot application that needs to perform LDAP queries. I'm trying to take the following recommendation from the Spring boot documentation:

> "Many Spring configuration examples have been published on the
>   Internet that use XML configuration. Always try to use the equivalent
>   Java-base configuration if possible."

In a Spring XML configuration file, I would have used:

```
 <ldap:context-source
          url="ldap://localhost:389"
          base="cn=Users,dc=test,dc=local"
          username="cn=testUser"
          password="testPass" />

   <ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" />

   <bean id="personRepo" class="com.llpf.ldap.PersonRepoImpl">
      <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
   </bean>
```

How would I configure this using a Java-based configuration? I need to be able to change URL, base, username, and password attributes of ldap:context-source without a code rebuild.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `<ldap:context-source>` XML tag produces an `LdapContextSource` bean and the `<ldap:ldap-template>` XML tag produces an `LdapTemplate` bean so that's what you need to do in your Java configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="ldap.contextSource")
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(ContextSource contextSource) {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }

    @Bean 
    public PersonRepoImpl personRepo(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
        PersonRepoImpl personRepo = new PersonRepoImpl();
        personRepo.setLdapTemplate(ldapTemplate);
        return personRepo;
    }
}
```

To allow you to change the configuration without a rebuild of your code, I've used Spring Boot's [`@ConfigurationProperties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties). This will look in your application's environment for properties prefixed with `ldap.contextSource` and then apply them to the `LdapContextSource` bean by calling the matching setter methods. To apply the configuration in the question, you can use an `application.properties` file with four properties:

```
ldap.contextSource.url=ldap://localhost:389
ldap.contextSource.base=cn=Users,dc=test,dc=local
ldap.contextSource.userDn=cn=testUser
ldap.contextSource.password=testPass
```

Comment: Odd - I cannot get this to work if I create a yaml configuration file - it works fine when I create a properties configuration.

Comment: It worked with the yaml configuration file as well. `ldap.contextSource:
    url: ldap://localhost:389
    base: cn=Users,dc=test,dc=local
    userDn: cn=testUser
    password: testPass`

Comment: No need for the 3rd bean and if you leave it away, the repo doesn't need public modifier but can be left at package scope (better for domain driven design)

Comment: How would the `personRepo` bean in the question's XML configuration be created without the third `@Bean` method above?